# Как с имитировать нажатие клавиши пульта в webview?

Tags: android-webview

У меня есть WebView, в котором открывается определенный сайт, который может обрабатывать нажатия на кнопки пульта, т.е. это приложение обычно стоит на android приставке для телевизора, чтобы можно было в этом приложении осуществлять управление пультом
Но так вышло, что мне нужно программно создать нажатие на кнопку пульта, когда пользователь в приложении что-либо сделает и чтобы это событие нажатия дошло до js сайта в webview.

Я это пробовал сделать так:

```
webview.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_BLUE, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_BLUE));
```

Но это не вышло

Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое можно провернуть?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, вот пример:

```
webview.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_GREEN));
```